# How to make an hover image in a grid text?

Tags: grid, hover, mouseevent, mouseover, mousehover

I'm triying to create a grid text with 3 columns. I want shows a image when putting the mouse on it.

Someone can help me? THANKS.

```
</div><div grid-row="" grid-pad="0" grid-gutter="0" grid-responsive="">
<div grid-col="x10" grid-pad="0" class=""><div style="text-align: center"><h1>03</h1></div></div>
<div grid-col="x10" grid-pad="0" class=""><h1>Italy</h1></div>
<div grid-col="x10" grid-pad="0" class=""><h1>1998</h1></div>
```

Comment: Your HTML has a lot of open tags in it and I'm not sure what you're using here to use `grid-col` attributes? Also what do you want to happen when someone hovers over what item?

Comment: Hi Dominik! I want that the row show an image when someone hover. It's like a table without header that each row have a different hover that show a different image.